# Managing a database with Java

Tags: java, ms-access

I have a MS Access database. My goal is to create a simple program to manage said database (i.e. add, modify, and/or delete information). Do I need to have Access installed in order for this program to work?

Comment: No, you need only the ODBC Access driver. I think last one is here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: @PeterMmm If I move my database to Java DB, I won't need to deal with ODBC and just with JDBC right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't really need to have the full Microsoft Access application installed on a machine in order to manipulate an Access .accdb or .mdb database from Java. In most cases you don't even have to use ODBC. For more information see the related question here:

[Manipulating an Access database from Java without ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390)